# Rails: Can you translate this SQL Query from MySQL to SQlite?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.1

can you translate this Rails code for MySQL:

```
def Customer.find_by_key(key)
  Customer.find(:all, :conditions => "pre_name REGEXP '.*#{key}.*' 
      OR sur_name REGEXP '.*#{key}.*' 
      OR street REGEXP '.*#{key}.*' 
      OR zip REGEXP '.*#{key}.*' 
      OR city REGEXP '.*#{key}.*' 
      OR phone_1 REGEXP '.*#{key}.*' 
      OR phone_2 REGEXP '.*#{key}.*' 
      OR email REGEXP '.*#{key}.*' 
      OR company REGEXP '.*#{key}.*'")
end
```

to SQlite3 code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `REGEXP` function isn't defined by default in sqlite3, you'll have to do a bit of work before.

Stick this in an initializer (for example `config/initializers/sqlite_regexp.rb`), works with rails 3.1 (see below for rails 3.0):

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter
  def initialize(db, logger, config)
    super
    db.create_function('regexp', 2) do |func, pattern, expression|
      regexp = Regexp.new(pattern.to_s, Regexp::IGNORECASE)

      if expression.to_s.match(regexp)
        func.result = 1
      else
        func.result = 0
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Code stolen [here](http://titusd.co.uk/2010/01/31/regular-expressions-in-sqlite/).

You could of course rewrite your query as in @mu's answer, but I figured it would be nice to know how to really implement the function.

**Update**

The code above doesn't work for rails 3.0, this should work:

```
require 'active_record/base'
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter'

module ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters
  class SQLite3Adapter < SQLiteAdapter
    def initialize(db, logger, config)
      super
      db.create_function('regexp', 2) do |func, pattern, expression|
        regexp = Regexp.new(pattern.to_s, Regexp::IGNORECASE)

        if expression.to_s.match(regexp)
          func.result = 1
        else
          func.result = 0
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/base.rb:1009:in \`method_missing': undefined local variable or method \`establish_connection' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NameError)`

Comment: The code works fine with rails 3.1, I'll check 3.0.7 (looks like that's what you're using).

Comment: wohoo great! the update works! I want to speak out big thanks to you, for giving me great help without a charge :) THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Replace these:

```
pre_name REGEXP '.*#{key}.*'
```

with LIKE:

```
pre_name LIKE '%#{key}%'
```

Or better, use placeholders:

```
:conditions => [
    "pre_name LIKE :pattern OR sur_name LIKE :pattern ...",
    { :pattern => '%' + key + '%' }
]
```

SQLite [understands REGEXP but it is not implemented by default](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like), you have to implement it yourself. You could add your implementation but there's no point when LIKE will probably do the job.